# Sailsjs table needs to be updated automatically without using any cron

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails.io.js

I am using SAILS JS and mysql adapter is being used. I have a model named as User with the following fields **ID, USERNAME, EMAIL, ACTIVE_STATUS and CREATED_DATE.**

By Default, active_status is set as 0. I want to update the status is 1 when created_date + 3 days is equal on Today.

Kindly suggest any possible ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you can use **MySQL’s Event Scheduler**

Activate it by: `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

Create event syntax:

```
CREATE EVENT `event_name` 
ON SCHEDULE schedule
[ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE] 
[ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
DO BEGIN
    -- event body
END;
```

The schedule can be assigned various settings, e.g.

- Run once on a specific date/time:
  AT ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM.SS’
  e.g. AT ‘2011-06-01 02:00.00’
- Run once after a specific period has elapsed:
  AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL n [HOUR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY|MINUTE]
  e.g. AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
- Run at specific intervals forever:
  EVERY n [HOUR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY|MINUTE]
  e.g. EVERY 1 DAY
- Run at specific intervals during a specific period:
  EVERY n [HOUR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY|MINUTE] STARTS date ENDS date
  e.g. EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 WEEK ENDS ‘2012-01-01 00:00.00’

Example:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; -- enable event scheduler.
SELECT @@event_scheduler;  -- check whether event scheduler is ON/OFF
CREATE EVENT e_store_ts  -- create your event
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 24 HOURS  -- run every 24 hours
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.users set active_status = 1
```

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html